# How to remove text between parenthesis in a file

Tags: ubuntu

Text in my file looks like this:

(0,1,12) 12.3, 3.3 , 4.5
I want to be able to remove whatever is within the parenthesis and parenthesis themselves too.

Comment: Exactly what can occur in the file? / What is your programming language?

Comment: 12.3, 3.3 , 4.5 can occur. But the paranthesis and whatever is in them can't. I'm using C to read all the floats in a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have sed...

```
sed -i -E "s/\([^)]*\)\s*//" /tmp/myfile.txt
```

This will edit myfile.txt in-place and remove the matched text.

To break down the regex - it will match an opening parenthesis, followed by any number of characters that are not closing parentheses, followed by a closing parenthesis, and then followed by any amount of whitespace (remove the \s* if you don't want that).